# How we can create a response handler in wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, url, plugins, woocommerce, response

I have to create a response handling URL in my custom developed plugin. Right now I am sending my data to third party website. I have to get response on a URL. Where I have retrieve all data and insert in to DB. Overall I have to create a response URL in wordpress Where I have to re-arrange data.

Comment: how are you sending the data ? own CURL code or wp functions ? or something else ?

Comment: Hi Alice, I am submitting a form to third party by post method. I want to sent a `response_url` parameter in posted data. They will send a `JSON` response on that URL.

Comment: I want to handle complete process by custom plugin.